# Unable to write Json output into file in java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to write simple JSON data into a file but seems my file is blank. It does not write anything. When I print output in java console then it shows me correct.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

obj.put("Phone Number:", "XXXXXXXXX");
obj.put("Fname:", "Mike");
obj.put("Lname:", "Miller");
obj.put("Street:", "101");

try {
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter("D:\\file1.json");
    file.write(obj.toJSONString());
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I saw similar code on the internet and SO as well. I am following same but still not sure why it is not writing output into a file.

Comment: Remember to close the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS may not write the data into hardware until you call flush:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    obj.put("Phone Number:","XXXXXXXXX");
    obj.put("Fname:","Mike");
    obj.put("Lname:","Miller");
    obj.put("Street:","101");
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter("D:\\file1.json");
    try {
        file.write(obj.toJSONString());
    }catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: it will work without flush .. since closing the connection will do the trick.

Comment: Will it keep existing record in file as well when I try to write multiple records?

Comment: @HelpingHands If you want to append, use `new FileWriter(fileName, true)`, otherwise old data will be overwritten.

Comment: Yep. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user27149 - when I add multiple data, it start { } brackets for each data. It should not start  and close {} only once?

Comment: @HelpingHands I'm not sure what do you mean by `it start { } brackets for each data`. Normally, you just need close one time when you dicide to end writting. And you can flush multiple times every time when you dicide to flush the data in buffer to disk.

Comment: @user27149 - i.e if you look here : [jsonoutput](http://prntscr.com/i816b8) , you will notice that with each data it start { and close } , but it should start ad close only once regardless of number of data.

Comment: @HelpingHands No, it should not start and close {} only once. Every valid `JSONObject` data should have its own {}.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164232/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-user27149).

Answer (score 3):

This is updated working version

```
public static void main(String...strings) throws IOException{   
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\\file1.json");
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("Phone Number:","XXXXXXXXX");
            obj.put("Fname:","Mike");
            obj.put("Lname:","Miller");
            obj.put("Street:","101");
            file.write(obj.toString());

        }catch (Exception E)
        {
            System.out.println(E);
            E.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            file.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you put the `file.close();` in the `try` block? Shouldn't it be in `finally`?

Comment: Since `FileWriter` implements `AutoClosable` it is even better to use try with resources : 
```try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("D:\\file1.json")) { ... }```

Comment: I have update the answer , I think its better to close the connection in finally block.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are not flushing the data into files. That's why data is not written into file. If you also want to keep the existing data into the file, try appending. Here is the updated code that will append new data to that existing file.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

 obj.put("Phone Number:","XXXXXXXXX");
 obj.put("Fname:","Mike");
 obj.put("Lname:","Miller");
 obj.put("Street:","101");

 try {

          FileWriter file = new FileWriter("D:\\file1.json", true); // true to append at the end of file.
           file.write(obj.toJSONString());
           file.flush()

            }catch (Exception E)
            {
                E.printStackTrace();

            }finally{
                file.close();
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing code by using any Files classes, I mean either you writing the content into file or reading from file, closing the stream is always best practice.

The code should be like this,

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("D:\\file1.json");

file.write(obj.toJSONString());
file.close();
```